# Performance measure giving different values for same operation

Tags: javascript, jsperf

I am trying to prove that one operation takes less time than 2 operation,so i am using below steps

```
var a=performance.now();
c=10+40;
d=80+90;
var b=performance.now();
console.log(b-a);
a=performance.now();
l=10+40;
b=performance.now();
console.log(b-a);
```

but results varies from execution to execution like below

```
0.009999997913837433
0.034999996423721313
//second execution    
0.010000001639127731
0
//Thirdexecution 
0.009999997913837433
0.015000000596046448
```

even i tried with

```
console.time('a');
 c=10+40;d=80+90;
console.timeEnd('a');
console.time('b');
l=10+40;
console.timeEnd('b');
```

even same operation not giving exact values

```
z=performance.now()
a=10+60;
x=performance.now()
console.log(x-z)
```

output:

```
//on first execution
0.009999999776482582
//on second execution
0.015000000596046448
```

still the result is same, please shed some light on this topic.

Comment: While `performance.now()` is _fairly_ accurate, I suspect you're still running into the limitations of just how accurate it is when you're running only one or two additions/assignments.  These operations are _very_ quick (and I wouldn't be surprised if the additions have been optimised away entirely by the JS engine, since they're constants).  In fact, you can remove the additions/assignments entirely, leaving only the calls to `performance.now` and the logging, and see similar results.

Comment: i hope first operation should take same or greater time than second but it is   not happening , may be that is my question how js executes this internally.

Comment: What I'm saying is that the resolution of `performance.now()` is around 5 microseconds.  If the thing you're timing takes less time than that, you can't really measure it with `performance.now()`.  Rather than comparing just 2 additions against 1, perhaps introduce a loop where you compare 200,000 against 100,000.  But also still be aware that the JS engine could be optimising that addition away entirely, since it's just adding two constants.

Comment: I tried with big values and for the same operations it is giving different results, I am concerned about that inconsistency in time,is it because of chrome thread that runs ?